# Backbone.js How to make collection only accept one class of model

Tags: backbone.js

I am new to backbone.js and I am trying to learn it. In the code below I want my collection called "JokesCollection" to only accept adding models of the class "Joke". How do I do achieve this? When setting "Collection" attribute "model" to a certain model, isn´t the collection supposed to only accept that model class and ensure homogeneity? Don´t seam so. When I assign attribute "model" in the "JokesCollection" class to "Joke" it still accepts adding models of class "Persson" witch is not what I want. I only want it to accept adding models of class "Joke".

```
Joke = Backbone.Model.extend ({
    initialize: function(){
        console.log("Joke was created");
    },
    defaults: {
        joke : "",
        date : "0",
    }
});

JokesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        console.log("JokesCollection was created");
    },
    model: Joke //  <=== Isn´t this supposed to ensure that the collection only accepts models of class "Joke"?
});

Person = Backbone.Model.extend ({
    initialize: function(){
        console.log("Person was created");
    },
    defaults: {
        username: "default",
        password: "default",
        email: "default"
    }
});



var person1 = new Person({username:"masterMind"});
var joke1 = new Joke({joke:"Girls are cute and funny hahahaha"});

jokesCollection = new JokesCollection();
jokesCollection.add(joke1);
jokesCollection.add(person1); // This adds a model of class "Person" to the collection. Witch is not what I want. It is not supposed to work! I want "jokesCollection" to only accept models of class "Joke".

console.log(jokesCollection.length); // length gets increased by 1 after adding "person1" to "jokesCollection". Again, it is no supposed to work from my point of view. I want "jokesCollection" to only accept models of class "Joke".
console.log(jokesCollection);
```

Answer (score 1):

From official docs:

**model** *collection.model*

> Override this property to specify the model class that the collection
>   contains. If defined, you can pass raw attributes objects (and arrays)
>   to add, create, and reset, and the attributes will be converted into a
>   model of the proper type.

Looks like will have to re-write `add` method something like this :

```
add: function(models, options) {

    var modelClass = this.model;
        isProperIns = this.models.every.(function(model){
            return model instanceof modelClass;
        });

    if (!isProperIns) {
        throw new Error("Some of models has unacceptable type")
    } 

    return this.set(models, _.extend({merge: false}, options, addOptions));
}
```

Comment: if you found this answer useful please mark it as right

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a `Collection`'s `model` property is *not* to limit which models the `Collection` can accept.  Rather, that property defines the `Model` class which the `Collection` will use when it needs to create a new `Model`.  For instance,when you pass an object literal of `Model` attributes (as opposed to an instantiated `Model`) to `JokesCollection.add`, or when you `fetch` models in to a `JokesCollection`, Backbone will use `Joke` as the `Model` to instantiate those new additions to the `Collection`.

There are two ways to ensure your `JokesCollection` is only populated with instances of `Joke`.  The first way is to never add `Model` instances to the `JokesCollection` directly, and instead either:

A) Bring new `Joke`s in from the server by calling `fetch` on a `JokesCollection`

B) add only "raw" `Model` attributes to the `JokesCollection`; don't add instantiated `Model`s

However, if you're concerned about a developer accidentally adding a non-`Joke` `Model` to the `Collection`, your other option (as first suggested by @Evgeniy) is to overwrite your `JokesCollection`'s `add` method.  Unlike @Evgeniy's answer though I would not recommend re-writing Backbone's internals.  Instead, I would use a simple overwrite that just calls the base Backbone method if possible:

```
add: function(models, options) {
    if (models instanceof Joke) {
        // Use the normal Backbone.Collection add method
        return Backbone.Collection.prototype.add.call(this, models, options);
    }
    var allModelsAreJokes = _(models).all(function(model) {
        return model instanceof Joke;
    ));
    if (allModelsAreJokes) {
        // Use the normal Backbone.Collection add method
        return Backbone.Collection.prototype.add.call(this, models, options);
    }
    // Handle the case where non-Jokes are passed in; either:
    // A) convert whatever was passed in to be a Joke:
    // var rawModels = _(models).isArray() ? _(models).invoke('toJSON') : model.toJSON();
    // return Backbone.Collection.prototype.add.call(this, rawModels, options);
    // B) just don't add anything
}
```